# File reader finding the average of the values from a txt file of the rows and columns without using arrays

Tags: java, filereader

I am given a txt file 7x3 grid of values and I'm supposed to find the average of each rows (7) and columns (3) without using arrays. The professor has guided us to printing the grid out but I'm not sure what to do next.

```
public static void main (String [] args){
    try{
        File file = new File("Cal.txt");
        Scanner scanFile = new Scanner(file);
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
            String string = scanFile.nextLine();
            System.out.println(string);
                    
        }

    }catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error occured...");
    }

}
```

The grid:

```
 40.0 30 10 
 25 76 1120
 0 1301 1823
 630 300 1000
 102 1100 1900
 982 200 239
 200 720 100
```

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Im confused as to how to separate each of the rows and columns to find the average

Comment: Look at the `String.split` method.

Comment: doesn't that require using an array? I am not allowed to use arrays

Comment: OK, very odd requirement. You'll need to loop over the characters in the string.

Comment: I agree. do you mean loop each number one by one? is there, not an easier way like just getting a complete row and column cause I did .nextDouble() and it printed the whole first row and now I just trying to find out how to add the values and how to get the rest of the other rows and columns

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scanner.hasNextFloat()` to check whether the next token is a float and `scanner.nextFloat()` to read the next float from the file. That way the average of all the values could be calculated like this:

```
public static void main (String [] args){
    try{
        File file = new File("Cal.txt");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        
        int count = 0;
        float sum = 0.0f;
        while(scanner.hasNextFloat()) {
            float val = scanner.nextFloat();
            count++;
            sum += val;
        }
        
        float average = sum / count;
        System.out.println("average: " + average);
        
        scanner.close();
    }catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error occured...");
    }
}
```